# How does Dermal Plating work vs. AA spell damage?

Tags: shadowrun-anarchy

We're playing Anarchy, and we're not sure about how Dermal Plating works versus a spell which has the AA property.

For example, if a caster causes 6P/AA damage with a Lightning bolt, and has 2 net successes, the damage is shared 4 to Armor, 2 to the Phys track. Where is Dermal Plating applied? Does it get subtracted from the 6P before that gets divided as per net successes and AA? Or does dermal plating reduce Phys damage first? (To me, the previous seems more logical, but not everyone in our group agrees.)

Q: **How is Dermal Plating and AA damage exactly applied, in combination, according to the rules?**

Answer (score 1):

First, Dermal Plating is not Armor. It is damage reduction. However, there should be a logical level of layers. I do Armor first (outermost layer), Dermal Plating next (middle layer), then Physical Damage (last layer).

So, in your example, the 6P hits the Armor first. Then the 2AA bypasses the Armor and runs into the Dermal Plating along with any P left over from above. If there's any damage left over after that it hits the Physical Damage Monitor.

Comment: This answer sounds good on the surface but seems opinion-based more than actually being backed-up by RAW (which is what the Asker is looking for). If you can cite the damage rules from the SR:A rulebook and any relevant features, your answer will be much stronger.